# How to stop at the next specific character in regex

Tags: html, regex, perl

I have many links in a large variable, and am using regex to extract links. The most ideal link would look like

```
<a href="/search/product/?vendornum=StaplesA03">View Stock</a>
```

And my regex works perfectly looking for two matches: The full Link and the vendornum.

```perl
/<a href="\/search\/\product/(.*?)\/.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/igm
```

But occasionally, the link will include other info such as a class, which has it's own quotes

```
<a href="/search/title/?vendornum=StaplesA03" class="product-lister" >View Stock</a>
```

And the extra "s throw me off. I cannot figure out the first match, which would be the first two "s

```
<a href="([^"]+)".*[^>].*?>View Stock</a>
```

I know regex can be very challenging, and I am using RegEx101.com, a real life saver.

But I just can't seem to figure out how to match the first pattern, the full href link, but excluding any other classes with their own before I reach the closing `>`

Any experts in regex the can guide me?

Comment: While you can use a regex as *part* of a parser, trying to write a parser out of a single regex is just complicating things for yourself. Don't re-invent this complicated wheel; use an exiting HTML parser.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la

Comment: I cleaned up the formatting of links in the question.  If I missed something and you don't like it now you can "roll back" to your (previous) version: click on "edited..." link above my username (below the question text, to the left of your name), scroll down that page, and you'll see the link "rollback."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is generally no reason to build an HTML parser by hand, from scratch, while there's usually trouble awaiting down the road; regex are picky, sensitive to details, and brittle to even tiny input changes, while requirements tend to evolve.  Why not use one of a few great HTML libraries?

An example with [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder)  (also extracting links, need stated in a comment)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $links_string = 
q(<a href="/search/title/?vendornum=StaplesA03" class="product-lister" >View Stock</a> 
  <a href="/search/title/?vendornum=StaplesA17" >View More Stock</a> );

my $dom = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($links_string);

my @links_html;
foreach my $tag ( $dom->look_down(_tag => "a") ) { 
    push @links_html, $tag->as_HTML;  # the whole link, as is
    my $href = $tag->attr("href"); 
    my ($name, $value) = $href =~ /\?([^=]+)=([^&]+)/;   #/
    say "$name = $value";

    say $tag->as_trimmed_text;     # or: ->as_text, keep some spaces
    # Or:
    # say for $tag->content_list;  # all children, and/or text
};
#say for @links_html;
```

I use a string with a newline between links for your "*many links in a large variable*", perhaps with some spaces around as well.  This doesn't affect parsing done by the library.

A few commments

- The workhorse here is [HTML::Element](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Element) class, with its powerful and flexible `look_down` method. If the string indeed has just links then you can probably use that class directly, but when done as above a full HTML document would parse just as well
- Once I get the URL I use a very simple-minded regex to pull out a single name-value pair. Adjust if there can be more pairs, or let me know. Above all, use [URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) if there's more to it
- The `as_trimmed_text` returns text parts of element's children, which in this case is presumably just the text of the link. The [content_list](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Element#content_list) returns all child nodes (same here)
- Use [URI::Escape](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/URI/lib/URI/Escape.pm) if there are percent-encoded characters to convert, per RFC 3986

This prints

```
vendornum = StaplesA03
View Stock
vendornum = StaplesA17
View More Stock
```

---

Another option is [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM), which is a part of a whole ecosystem

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Mojo::DOM;

my $links_string = q( ... );  # as above

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($links_string);
 
my @links_html;
foreach my $node ( $dom->find('a')->each ) { 
    push @links_html, $node->to_string;  # or $node, gets stringified to HTML
    my $href = $node->attr('href');
    my ($name, $value) = $href =~ /\?([^=]+)=([^&]+)/;   #/
    say "$name = $value";

    say $node->text;
}
#say for @links_html;
```

I use the same approach as above, and this prints the same. But note that [Mojolicious](https://docs.mojolicious.org/) provides for yet other, convenient ways. Often, calls are chained using a range of its useful methods, and very fine navigation through HTML is easily done using CSS selectors.

While it is probably useful here to loop as above, as an example we can also do

```
my $v = $dom -> find('a') 
    -> map( 
        sub { 
            my ($name, $value) = $_->attr('href') =~ /\?(.+?)=([^&]+)/;  
            say "$name = $value"; 
            say $_->text;
        }
    );
```

what prints the same as above. See [Mojo::Collection](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Collection) to better play with this.

The parameters in the URL can be parsed using [Mojo::URL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::URL) if you really know the name

```
my $value = Mojo::URL->new($href) 
    -> query
    -> param('vendornum');
```

If these aren't fixed then [Mojo::Parameters](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Parameters) is useful

```
my $param_names = Mojo::Parameters
    -> new( Mojo::URL->new($href)->query ) 
    -> names
```

where `$param_names` is an arrayref with names of all parameters in the query, or use

```
my $pairs = Mojo::Parameters->new( Mojo::URL->new($href)->query ) -> pairs;
# Or
# my %pairs = @{ Mojo::Parameters->new(Mojo::URL->new($href)->query) -> pairs };
```

which returns an arrayref with all name,value pairs listed in succession (what can be directly assigned to a hash, for instance).

---

An HTML document can be nicely parsed using `XML::LibXML` as well.

Comment: What I really enjoyed about this solution is that I still get to use the regex I finally figured out.  Because that was hard.  Thank you

Comment: Of course, I didn't need the links gutted.  For another part of the app, I do need th whole link. Looking to see if there's a property

Comment: @LuisC329  OK, I'm glad you like it :).  In this case regex is still fine for the query, but if things get more complicated you'd want libraries for that as well (like the liked ones).  What do you mean by "_the whole link_" ?  By all means browse the docs and you'll find a way!  Or let me know...

Comment: @LuisC329  (i meant "linked ones" for the libraries, not "liked" :)

Comment: I meant I also for other purposed need the entire <a = href "....">.....</a> line for another reason.  I'll find a way in the manuals, am not dyslexic, but I have some weird reading problem, and it's worse when not reading off of paper

Comment: OK, I see.    Added to the code in the answer.  With `HTML::TreeBuilder` that is `->as_HTML` method, which returns the node as HTML so in this case exactly teh whole link. With `Mojo::DOM` when you use the `$node` object where text might be expected it gets ["stringified"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary#stringification), to its HTML. (I also find reading digital content slightly ... disorienting, if that's the right word -- without reading issues otherwise)

Comment: @LuisC329 In the meanwhile, I've edited a little more and added a couple of useful links.

Comment: @LuisC329  (I realize I didn't tag you in one message above. I think you should still get notified in this case but if not here it is...)

Comment: No tag notification. But thanks to you I was able to do it all, except find the original full link from <a>.....</a>, but it's a good tool, thanks

Comment: @LuisC329  Cool.  As for the original link (`<a>...</a>`), maybe I didn't explain it right: I added that to both programs.  As it processes the string with all links (or any HTML document with links in it in fact), it stores each link as a string in `@links_html`.  It's the first line in the loop (for each program), that gets the whole link and adds it to the array.  The line that prints the array after the loop is commented out, uncomment it to see the actual links.

Answer (score 1):

If I read correctly, you'd like to extract the vendornum value from the URL, and the link text. Best to use an html parser.

If you want to live dangerously with code that can break you can use a regex to parse html:

```
my $html = '<a href="/search/title/?vendornum=StaplesA03" class="product-lister" >View Stock</a>';
if($html =~ /<a href="[^\?]*\?vendornum=([^"]*)[^>]*>([^<]*).*$/) {
    print "vendornum: $1, link text: $2\n";
} else {
    print "no match";
}
```

Output:

```
vendornum: StaplesA03, link text: View Stock
```

Explanation:

- `vendornum=([^"]*)` - scan for `vendornum=`, and capture everything after that until just before `"`
- `[^>]*>` - scan over remaining attributes, such as `class=""`, up to closing angle bracket
- `([^<]*)` - capture link text
- `.*$` - scan up to end of text

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should consider using [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder) for things like this.  Once you get the hang of it it can be easier than coming up with regexes.  However for quick and dirty tasks, a regex is fine.

```perl
$text =
'<a href="/search/title/?vendornum=StaplesA03" class="product-lister" >View Stock</a>
<a x=y href="/search/product/?Vendornum=651687" foo=bar>View Stockings</A>';

$regex =
qr{<a\s[^>]*?href="(?<link>[^"]*?\?vendornum=(?<vendornum>\w+)[^"]*)"[^>]*?>(?<desc>(?:(?!</a>).)*)</a>}i;

while($text =~ m/$regex/g){ Data:Dump::pp1 %+; }
```

Returns

```
{
  # tied Tie::Hash::NamedCapture
  desc => "View Stock",
  link => "/search/title/?vendornum=StaplesA03",
  vendornum => "StaplesA03",
}
{
  # tied Tie::Hash::NamedCapture
  desc => "View Stockings",
  link => "/search/product/?Vendornum=651687",
  vendornum => 651687,
}
```

HTH